# close window then open in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-layout

When I click on the button to create a new folder, and my problem is that (I want this page is to be disabled and every time I wants that), just like accounts in game.

I make a class that makes a window, but when I close that and open it (again), all of the information is deleted (I create a `lable` , a `button` and an `entry` when I click on the button the `lable.config(text=f"{entry.get()}")`, but when I again come to this page, I see the `lable` don't get the text of the entry the first time I came to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I found the solution is to put the first page/main page in a loop and when the loop is done you create a new canvas that can be later destroyed.

This solution is basic, doe it does the same purpose.